# How to get color out of cleartype text image?

Tags: colors, fonts

I currently have an image of Notepad that uses a specific color in its dialog:

[image]

I'd like to obtain the color used here, but at zooming in it looks like this (I guess because of ClearType):

[image]

It's basically a combination of different colors, so that it looks better without zooming in.

How do I obtain the original color used here to paint the text? I'd like to use the same color, but I don't know which of all those colors in the zoomed-in picture to pick.

Comment: It's called [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end was:

- Draw a string in any color myself (creating a Label in VS.NET).
- Make a screenshot and see which pixel of which letter uses exactly the same color when using ClearType and that you supplied in VS.NET (ForeColor property). This is, for example, the pixels in the second column of the second downstroke of the letter 'n'.
- Capture the color of that pixel of that letter the Notepad dialog.

... and then you get `rgb(0, 51, 188)`. When I use that color, my custom Label looks just like the Notepad dialog, so I guess I've solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off cleartype and try again.

Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display

Comment: I'm sorry but although  some text in Windows does change, the text in this dialog doesn't...